# Excel HTTPS links and openAM

Tags: excel, https, openam, opensso

I have an excel sheet that contains https links. I found that the Excel tunnels the connection in a weird way, and my openAM authentication provider doesn't authenticate me.

When the link is direectly pasted into the browser, it owrks. When it's clicked in the Excel sheet, I see this behavior in Fiddler:

`Result - 200 | Protocol - HTTP | Host: Tunnel to | URL: MyOpenAmURL:443`

Is this a known issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This is Fiddler ... it tells you that an SSL connection is established.

There is no HTTPS-Protocol, only HTTP-Protocol.

If you use Microsoft Network Monitor (downloadable from Microsoft) you will see the SSL handshake messages.

-Bernhard